# An error occurred on insert in GroceryCrud

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter, grocery-crud

I face this error when I'm trying to save the add form from Grocery Crud..

[image]

this error only show up at my server where i change the http port into 88 for port forwarding issue, but the script were working normally in my localhost at my own laptop..

did the port change impact the grocery crud? can some one tell me how to fix it since I really have to change the port since port 80 and 8080 is already used..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure the Codeigniter *base_url* property with the port you are using (in application/config/config.php):

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:88/';
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but I'm using bootstrap theme

1.first set bootstrap theme:

$crud->set_theme('bootstrap');
2.in the file grocery_crud/themes/bootstrap/js/form/add.min.js 
replace the code:
error:function(){alert(message_insert_error),a("#FormLoading").hide()}
with the code:
error:function(data){alert(JSON.stringify(data)),a("#FormLoading").hide()}

and it will show you what the error is about